# Can a link pointing to a URL starting with javascript:// execute any code?

Tags: javascript, html, xss

I have discovered a vulnerability in a software that I’m maintaining where it is possible for users to put `javascript:` and `data:` links into content that will be seen by others.

However, there is a mechanism in place that will prepend `http://` to any link href that does not begin with `[a-z0-9]+://`, which basically makes it possible to only add malicious link hrefs that start with `javascript://` or `data://`. I would like to find out how big of a security issue this is, so my question is, is there any way to exploit such links to execute JavaScript code when clicking them?

My understanding is that `javascript://` link can only contain a JavaScript one-line comment, so no code can be executed. I suppose that a one-line comment can only be ended by a newline (`\n`), but I am unsure whether there is a way to bring such a newline into the link href. I tried different methods like `href="javascript://
alert('test')"`, `href="javascript://&#10;alert('test')"`, `href="javascript://%0aalert('test')"` and one with a `\0` character, but none of them seemed to execute any code.

For `data:` URIs, I guess it is not possible to make up any valid one that starts with `data://`, but maybe there is still some browser where this could be exploited somehow?

Comment: `href="javascript:(function() { anything goes here and will be executed in scope of current page })()"`

Comment: FWIW, it looks like Chrome sanitizes the newline character out of the URL, as accessing the `.href` attribute of the link yields `"javascript://alert('test')"`. The newline is present in `a.getAttribute('href')`.

Comment: Also make sure one cannot add `#" onclick="anything goes here"` to the href

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks, HTML characters are already getting escaped, and the javascript: link that you wrote does not start with javascript://

Comment: Not sure whether you can use it in your software, but adding a [Content Security Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy) will make it even harder to get a `javascript:` link to work (you shouldn't rely only on it, proper escaping is better, but it's a good additional measure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with a few possible issues here, as it was kind of a fun challenge. Even if none of these work, I think you can make this more secure pretty easily, and it'll be worth the peace of mind. In any case, here's some payloads I came up with.

#### new line

You said this doesn't work for you, but it works for me in Chrome (`Windows 10/69.0.3497.100`). This is the most obvious work around as well as the only working one I could come up with. Perhaps you had a typo when you tried? While HTML entity encoding won't do it, simple URL encoding should... If your source ends up looking like this, then it should work:

[`<a href="javascript://%0aalert(document.location)">xss test</a>` (jsfiddle PoC)](https://jsfiddle.net/63x7ufaw/)

#### incomplete regex

You said it must "begin with `[a-z0-9]+://` but that regex doesn't cover the "begin" part, so something like this could match:

`javascript:alert(1);//abc://foo.bar`

You probably have something like `^[a-z0-9]:\/\/` or are using a language that wraps "startsWith()" or something similar. Just worth mentioning.

#### nested protocols

I don't think there's much here, but it's worth a look. And it's an attack vector that you may not have considered.

`view-source://data:text/html,<script>alert(1);</script>`

For one, this shouldn't execute anything since it's `view-source`. For two, it should give a CORS error (I think). And finally, even if it did execute, it would be executing in a different context than your page (they could just link to a malicious site if that was their goal). So all around kinda weak. That being said, perhaps there are other nested protocols that could be problematic.

#### request forgery

Not exactly XSS, but still a potential issue. An attacker may be able to link to an existing page on your site, such as `https://example.com/account/delete`. If they can control the display name of the link, this could make it pretty convincing. Even if they don't control the display name, you can create some pretty confusing uris that mask where it actually goes (various encoding techniques). You may not have any URLs like that on your site (good work!), but it does happen often.

#### phishing/malicious links

This may be obvious, but it's important to be aware that a user can make a link to a site that copies the look of your site (or some other site). This is just a general concern that comes with allowing arbitrary hyperlinks. If your userbase is particularly vulnerable to this, many sites redirect external links to a warning page (this can be done as simply as a little js, ex: `onclick="return confirm('you sure you want to do that?')"`. Though, I don't know how effective these things really are - it's just something you see.

#### conclusion

There's probably a million things we could rattle off that may or may not cause security issues. In the end, it's probably worthwhile to enforce a whitelist of what protocols you want to allow. Do you want people to be able to include links like `mailto:`, `ssh:`, `slack:`, `file:`, etc? I would do a client-side regex for starting with http(s), and then in the backend use a URI parser to confirm that the scheme is indeed http(s), and present a warning if not. This is more of a user experience aspect, but if you are worried most users will type something like "www.example.com", you can just give them a client-side warning that it should start with http(s) (or just have it there by default). For bonus points, perhaps consider using a reputation checking API and presenting the results alongside the url, rejecting any domains with a bad reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Indeed I managed to exploit it by using your %0a approach. I think the reason why I didn't manage before was that in the application, for some reason URLs are getting decoded, so I had to double-encode the newline (`%250a`).

Comment: Ah, interesting. Be sure to confirm that the decoding process doesn't allow for a stored XSS. e.g. `%22%20%2F%3E%3Csvg%20onload%3Dalert%281%29%2F%3E` => `"/> <svg onload=alert(1)/>`.